# How to fix the error "This declaration shadows an existing declaration" in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I am writing some code to design a smart contract. But i am constantly getting the same error every time saying "Warning: This declaration shadows an existing declaration". I haven't found the possible solution since i am new to the solidity language:

```
contract Diamondtracability {

uint private diamondIDengravement;
uint private diamondIDdatabase;
uint public buyerID;

   //uint private diamondIDengravement = diamondIDdatabase;
   //string[] public diamondDirectory;

constructor() public {
    diamondIDengravement = 1;
    diamondIDdatabase = 1;
    buyerID = 1;
}

function set(uint diamondIDengravement) public {
    diamondIDengravement = _diamondIDdatabase
}

function get(uint) interface returns public {
    return diamondIDengravement;return diamondIDdatabase;return buyerID
}
```

}

The function as stated below is supposed to work, but I can't find a solution myself:

```
function set(uint diamondIDengravement) public {
diamondIDengravement = _diamondIDdatabase
}
```

Answer (score 9):

That's not an error. It's a warning.

But you probably want something like this:

```
function set(uint _diamondIDengravement) public {
    diamondIDengravement = _diamondIDengravement;
}
```

Basically, you already have a state variable named `diamondIDengravement`, so it's a bad idea to name a function parameter with the same name. You can use any other name for the parameter, but by convention if you just want to avoid a name collision, adding an underscore in front is a good way to indicate that's what you're doing.

But your code makes very little sense, so it's hard to tell what you want to do. (I'm not sure what you intended `set` to do, so I took a guess.)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the different name of parameters because you are using the same name which you declared as in a state variable.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change **diamondIDengravement**  where it is defined in the function definition. By changing, I just mean to create a bit difference in the spelling, you can do this just by adding a `_`  in front of diamondIDengravement.
Hence, it will be like

```
function set(uint _diamondIDengravement) public {
```